# Stack Exchange reputation graph total reputation overlay

Tags: script, reputation

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: totals box on global reputation graph]

[image: reputation graph with "Network Total" series enabled]

### About

Adds a small box to the global reputation graph to indicate the user's total reputation across all sites where the user has at least 200 reputation. Also displays the total "shown" reputation, which is the total reputation of all of the accounts currently graphed (either all of the user's graphable sites, or just the top five).

Adds a "Network Total" series to the graph that displays accumulated Stack Exchange network reputation over time. The enabled/disabled setting is persisted in local storage for convenience.

If you'd like to see something like the totals overlay implemented natively, go check out [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/87774/display-combined-rep-total-on-stack-exchange-users-reputation-page). Likewise, if you're interested in seeing the Network Total series implemented natively, be sure to throw an up vote in the direction of [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/142111/add-an-option-to-show-cumulative-score-on-the-reputation-graph).

#### Download

[install / update script](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/raw/master/stack-utilities-global-rep.user.js) – [view source](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/blob/master/stack-utilities-global-rep.user.js)

#### Platform

The script should work under all major userscript-supporting browsers. Please [file a bug](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/issues) if you encounter any issues.

### Contact

[Tim Stone](https://stackapps.com/users/4746/tim-stone) actively maintains this script.

Feedback can be [given on GitHub](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/issues), or by "@lerting" the maintainer on [Meta Stack Overflow chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general).

### Code

To fork the code, please visit the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities).